# 2d array copy column and row and proof if the contains is equal to or not

Tags: java, android, copy, multidimensional-array

I would like to proof whether there is a `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` in my j-th column and row. But I do not know how I can do this, by not having an exploding time complexity. This means I do not want to use for loops for doing this. But I haven't found any alternative way.
Do you know one?
My second thing is I want to copy some columns and/or rows from my 2d array in Java. For rows I can simply use `Array[i]` to copy it. But for columns I cannot use such form of code. But is there a possibility to do it without for loops?

Comment: How is your array filled?

Comment: It is filled with Float values with for loops. So every entry is set separatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have the following options.

1. Wrap the array into a sepearate class. Use getters and setters where you can check the values when they are assigned and do, whatever you need to do with it.
2. Loop over the array once it is filled.

After all, there is no way around it that you have to loop if you don't use the first approach. If you have a signal when the array is finished you only have to do it once, but for a more precise approach it would be helpfull to see the code how you fill the array and how you are using the array.